# How to search for controllers in multiple directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I created a very simple plugin system in my Rails application. These plugins can bring along their own views and controllers in their subfolder.

Thus, when searching for controllers, I want Rails to look in one of these directories:

- `app/controllers`
- `plugins/plugin1/controllers`
- `plugins/plugin2/controllers`

I added those plugin directories to my autoload_path in `application.rb`, but that had no effect.

Comment: You should probably consider use of mountable engines http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: I know they exist. But I don't want to use them and have my reasons for that...

Comment: I'm just saying it's very much not-the-rails-way.

Comment: Yeah, I must say, I'm struggling a bit with finding out where I go "the Rails way" and where it is flexible enough to let me build my own thing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution is as easy as adding the directories to the `config.autoload_paths` setting.

Each new folder can be added in `config/application.rb` like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/plugins/plugin1/controllers/**/"]
```

This actually makes sure the folder and all its subdirectories are autoloaded.

(I wasn't able to make this work previously, because my controller had a non-existent parent class. For some reason, Rails told me the route didn't exist instead of showing that error.)